# Adding Information To JUnit Test Results via tycho-surefire-plugin

Tags: tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

The test results of JUnit tests have a `properties` tag with a bunch of properties. What is logged seems to be at the discretion of each executor of the tests.

I want to process the XML files further, so it would be really nice to have the same keys each time. For `maven-surefire-plugin` that's pretty straightforward:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <propertyName>propertyValue1</propertyName>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This adds the line `<property name="propertyName" value="propertyValue1"/>` to the XML result file.

For the `tycho-surefire-plugin`, I tried the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <propertyName>propertyValue1</propertyName>
        </systemPropertyVariables>

        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                <name>propertyName</name>
                <value>propertyValue2</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>

        <argLine>-DpropertyName=propertyValue3</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

...but neither of these values is printed inside the XML result.

How do I add information to the JUnit test results using `tycho-surefire-plugin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of the `tycho-surefire-plugin`](https://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#systemProperties) states that you should use the `<systemProperties>` map:

```
<configuration>
  <systemProperties>
    <propertyName>propertyValue1</propertyName>
  </systemProperties>
</configuration>
```

This will start the forked test JVM with `-DpropertyName=propertyValue1`.